# C#: Cannot get 100% score for "Path" www.testdome.com/questions/c-sharp/path/12280?visibility=1

Tags: c#, path

Practice on the C# question on the testdome https://www.testdome.com/questions/c-sharp/path/12280?visibility=1. I only get 75% score. Could someone help me to get 100% score? Code attached below

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Path {
    public string CurrentPath { get; private set; }

    public Path(string path) {
        this.CurrentPath = path;
    }

    public void Cd(string newPath) {
        //absolute path
        if (newPath.StartsWith("/")) {
            CurrentPath = newPath;
        } else if (newPath.Contains("../")) {
            var pathList = new LinkedList<string>(CurrentPath.Split('/'));
            var newPathList = newPath.Split('/');
            foreach (var item in newPathList) {
                if (item == "..") {
                    if (pathList.Count > 0)
                        pathList.RemoveLast();
                } else {
                    pathList.AddLast(item);
                }
            }
            CurrentPath = string.Join("/", pathList);
            if (!CurrentPath.StartsWith("/"))
                CurrentPath = "/" + CurrentPath;
         } else {
            CurrentPath += "/" + newPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code misses test cases when `..` appears at the end of the path, e.g.

```
some-dir/dir/..
```

Your code prepends `/` and returns the path without further processing, because the string does not contain `"../"` search string. Removing forward slash from that string fixes this problem.

Comment: Spot on! Thanks a lot.